# issues passing a value from the activity to the Datasource

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

After trying to get a text from the database i got this error:

```
12-21 09:54:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(25745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 09:54:10.948: E/AndroidRuntime(25745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ggservice.democracy/com.ggservice.democracy.sondaggioActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, preferita, nome FROM sondaggi WHERE _id=
```

**this is the call:**

```
Cursor values = datasource.getDomanda(strcategory );
        if (values.moveToFirst()) // data?
               System.out.println(values.getString(values.getColumnIndex("domanda"))); 

               values.close();
```

**And it calls this:**

```
public Cursor getDomanda(String id) {
            List<sondaggi> domande = new ArrayList<sondaggi>();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                    allCategorieColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
              sondaggi sondaggio = cursorToSondaggi(cursor);
              domande.add(sondaggio);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            return cursor;
          }
```

the id seams empty, but i know there is a value there, i have tested the variable passage. i mean, if i Toast the strcategory it return the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chnage

```
  Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                    allCategorieColumns,
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=",
                    new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

to

```
  Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SONDAGGI,
                    allCategorieColumns,
                    MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

Comment: oh, the question mark, thanks a lot, i feel so naive as i'm trying to figure out how to code in a new lenguage :(

Comment: @peorthyr : ohh! what about your Long to Int convertion issue? have you solved it

Comment: i'm working on it, as you can see i have some more problems... :D

Comment: @peorthyr : yes i see you have lots of issue from when user click on listview item and to save/retrieve from database. try it